# CFData (store) increases upto 200MB when downloading images throughout NSData -initWithContentsOfURL in Background thread

Tags: ios, crash, instruments, memory-warning, cfdata

Im using NSData -initWithContentsOfURL in a background thread to download some 4k images. I can see in Instruments that my CFData (store) keeps growing and goes upto 200MB (at which point btw I crash) although Im using this code to clear the cache

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
[sharedCache release];
```

that i found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922264/constantly-growing-memory-allocation-while-fetching-images-over-http-in-ios)

The part of the code that I know for sure is causing this problem (I commented it and the memory didn't grow beyond 50MB) is:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *serverPath = [serverImageInfo valueForKey:@"ImagePath"];
NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[serverPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

NSString *directoryPath = [Utilities directorypath];
if (image != NULL && [image length] > 0)
{
    //NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:directoryPath];

    NSString *path = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ArrangementImages"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageInfo.Name];
    [image writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    self.imageInfo.ImagePath = path;
    [path release];
}

[sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
[sharedCache release];

//image = nil;
[image release];
```

Comment: So why not just remove that part?  I'm not entirely convinced the url cache has anything to do with your code anyway (it is used with NSURLRequest objects, not NSURL objects)

Comment: how do i download images if i remove that part???

Comment: @borrrden i replaced initWithContentsOfURL with NSURLRequest -sendSynchronousRequest.....no change in memory....allocations still show all my images as living objects in cfdata (store) and keeps growing as images are downloaded

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  Which part are you commenting out?

Comment: Did you check for leaks in instruments?

Comment: @borrrden i comment out the nsdata part and then everything is fine but i did it just to check where the problem was....i need hat to download images

Comment: @xs2bush If you are going to be downloading files, I recommend using AFNetworking.  It is easy to use and works very well.  I don't see anything wrong with this code from looking at it a bit so I think the problem may be somewhere else (Do you use that data again somewhere else?)

Comment: no. i actually found the solution i put this code in an autorelease pool and voila!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used [sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses]; in conjunction with an autorelease pool....and my cfdata(store) didnt increase beyond 15 MB although i downloaded 4k images.

Comment: How can I know what is the size of cache memory I mean you said "didnt increase beyond 15 MB" please tell me